# Change mat-slide-toggle click color

Tags: html, css, angular, colors, angular-material

When I click the element it is visible a shadow of the color that the element is suppoused to be, in this case yellow

[image]

and i want to make that shadow to a green color, but I dont know how to change it, here is my code.

HTML

```
   <mat-checkbox id="tractor{{element.id}}" checked="{{element.tractor}}"></mat-checkbox>
```

CSS

```
::ng-deep .mat-slide-toggle.mat-checked:not(.mat-disabled) .mat-slide-toggle-thumb {
background-color: rgb(50, 170, 118); /*replace with your color*/
}

    ::ng-deep .mat-slide-toggle.mat-checked:not(.mat-disabled) .mat-slide-toggle-bar {
        background-color: rgb(113, 226, 147);  /*replace with your color*/
    }
```

Comment: Can you share that example on stackblitz? Then I could show you CSS that works.

Comment: I dont know how but let me try

Comment: sorry I dont know how to use stackblitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding style to .mat-ripple-element class, this should override the shadow colour.

```css
::ng-deep
.mat-slide-toggle.mat-checked .mat-ripple-element{
    background-color: green;
}
```